# Unknown argument ""on field""of type Mutation with React Native app using Apollo Client and Apollo Server

Tags: react-native, neo4j, cypher, graphql, apollo

```javascript
const Profile = t.struct({
 name: t.String,
 city: t.String,
 about: t.String,
});

const UPDATE_USER = gql`
 mutation UpdateAccountForm(
   $id: ID!
   $name: String
   $about: String
   $city: String
 ) {
   UpdateUser(id: $id, name: $name, about: $about, city: $city) {
     id
   }
 }
`;

export default class UpdateAccountForm extends React.Component {
 state = {
   user: {
     name: '',
     about: '',
     city: '',
   },
 };
 render() {
   const { user } = this.state;
   return (
     <Mutation mutation={UPDATE_USER}>
       {(UpdateUser, { data }) => (
         <View style={styles.container}>
           <Image
             source={require('../Images/logoBlue.jpg')}
             style={{ width: 120, height: 120 }}
           />
           <Form
             type={Profile}
             value={user}
             options={options}
             onChange={this.onChange}
           />
           <Button
             title="Submit"
             type="clear"
             titleStyle={{ color: '#4873a6' }}
             onPress={() => this._handleSaveAccount(UpdateUser)}
             containerStyle={{ marginTop: 20 }}
           />
         </View>
       )}
     </Mutation>
   );
 }

  componentDidMount = () => {
   client
     .query({
        query: gql`
         query getUser($id: ID!) {
          User(id: $id) {
              name
              city
              about
           }
          }
       `,
       variables: { id: this.props.loggedInUserId },
     })   

  _handleSaveAccount = async UpdateUser => {
   const { name, about, city } = this.state.user;
   const id = this.props.loggedInUserId;
   const { goToBookshelf } = this.props;

   await UpdateUser({
     variables: {
       id,
       name,
       about,
       city,
     },
   }).then(() => {
     goToBookshelf(id);
   });
 };
}
```

Can somebody help us identify what the issue is here?

It seems to be working for some mutations and query and sometimes it
throws unpredictable errors like this. We are using react expo and 
apollo client  for the front end and graphql, apollo client and neo4j on the back.

The schema

```
type User {
  id: ID!
  uid: ID!
  name: String!
  username: String!
  email: String!
  about: String
  city: String
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about datatype "id: ID" ? graphQL treats it as unique and similar as String.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot `data:{}`

```
const UPDATE_USER = gql`
 mutation UpdateAccountForm(
   data:{$id: ID!, $name: String}     
 ) {
   UpdateUser(id: $id, name: $name) {
     id
   }
 }
`;
```

Double check if you can send ID because sometimes it is auto created!

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Only thing I can see a problem is separator called comma ","

```
const UPDATE_USER = gql`
     mutation UpdateAccountForm($id: ID!, $name: String,
                             $about: String,$city: String ) {
          UpdateUser(id: $id, name: $name, about: $about, city: $city) {
             id
          }
     }`;
```

Or Please check mutation variable type passed by form in mutation.

Comment: I cannot see the comma in my code? Explain a little further please Ashok?